# How to provide filter tab in timelion charts?

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

I am trying out some timelion visualizations in Kibana. In it I am not sure how to provide filter tab for the data.
For example, yearly country population data and filter tab to filter it based on zone and state.
Usually a timelion expression is just like ".es()" and some functions which can be appended to it like

```
.es(*).bars().label("Population")
```

I don't want to specify filter under ".es(q=???)" as this will make the filter static and the user won't be able to use filtering directly. ( In this case, every time user has to go to edit timelion window and edit filter there.)

Comment: You simply need to save your Timelion expression as a dashboard panel and then add it to your dashboard. Then on the dashboard you can add any filter as usual and the timelion panel will get properly filtered.

Comment: Hi @val, the information you provided is I already tried and I am able to see timelion in dashboard. However this not exactly my trouble point. What I want is to provide filter on timelion visualization itself so every time user don't have to click on edit on that chart and edit filters/query in timelion expression...

Comment: You can add filters on the dashboard and save the dashboard with the filters, can't you?

Comment: Doing that will be just be another static dashboard with filtered data. Like filtered data for India. Following this approach will necessitate to go over search window and edit filter every time there and save it in order to see filtered visualization.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify a lucene query string as the q argument to .es() as in
.es(q=field:value)
That query string would only affect this time series and not interfere with the rest of your dashboard.